# How to disable KDE suspend/screen lock notifications?

Tags: 12.10, power-management, notification, kde4

Every time I close the lid on my laptop it plays a sound. Similarly, I'm getting a notification that the screen has been locked when I wake it up again. I've looked under KDE power management system notifications, but there are no options for this.

Where can I configure and disable these notifications? In either case there's no need for a notification, as the I'm the one performing the action or the effect is obvious.

Comment: For reference, this question has been answered [here on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/543189/how-to-make-kde-desktop-stop-creating-notification-the-screen-is-being-locked).

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings. In the window that opens, choose Common Appearance and Behavior, then Application and System Notifications, then Manage Notifications. *Then* be careful to choose the right drop down menu under "Event Source" which is a selector just under the tabs in the main (right) pane. It comes up in the first one, Accessibility, but if press the down arrow at the extreme right, there are some twenty other categories. One of those is Notifications for KDE Power Management System.

After that marathon, go take a rest. (Honestly. Why do they have to make it so convoluted!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't see an option for disabling these particular notifications in there.